# Mysql Sum Conditional

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the total cost from the table below and if `Include_Extra` is set, use the value in the corresponding `Extra_Seat_Cost` column. I'm new to mysql, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
| ID | Cost | Extra_Seat_Cost | Include_Extra |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+
|  3 |   20 |      15         |       1       |
|  4 |   10 |      5          |       0       |
+----+------+-----------------+---------------+
```

The result should yield total = $45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM` with `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT SUM(Cost + CASE WHEN Include_Extra = 1   --if Include_Extra is bool delete = 1
                       THEN COALESCE(Extra_Seat_Cost,0) 
                       ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM table_name;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5085e/1/0)**</kbd>

I've added `COALESCE` in case `Extra_Seat_Cost` can be nullable. number + `NULL` produces `NULL`.

---

If you have grouping column use:

```
SELECT group_column, SUM(Cost + CASE WHEN Include_Extra = 1 
                                     THEN COALESCE(Extra_Seat_Cost,0) 
                                     ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM table_name;
GROUP BY group_column;
```